# Shopping fight dataset

Tags: data-request

I am looking for list of [fights](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=00E4fISNyso) between [shoppers](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2852585/Mayhem-Black-Friday-begins-Shoppers-clash-supermarkets-trying-grab-bargains-Boots-Game-Curry-s-PC-world-websites-crash-thousands-start-hunt-Christmas-deals.html) with as many following fields as possible:

- location (GPS/shop name)
- date/time
- number of people involved and demographics information about them
- outcome (medical/legal)

I am especially interested in the USA.